# Sysprep Not Working After Updating the windows?

Tags: windows-10, sysprep

am facing the problem from sysprep,issue is after i update windows version 1909 to version 202h sysprep showing error (Sysprep was not able to validate your Windows installation), in version 1909 sysprep working perfactly but in 202h version is not working.
can any body help me about this problem facing nowadays.
appriciate in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please include the contents of the file `C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log`, or at least the last messages. On some systems this file is at `%WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther\setupact.log`.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/sysprep-was-not-able-to-validate-your-windows-installation